# Looking for a particular solution to a wiring problem

Tags: wiring

I don't even know what such a part would be called, but here's my problem: I have a bunch of electrical equipment (sensors, relays, etc) on one side of a piece of stainless steel sheet metal. I have a data acquisition card on the other side of said sheet metal. I need to connect the equipment to the DAQ through the sheet metal. I would like to use screw terminals, if possible.

Does a thing like that exist, and what would it be called?

Comment: Is this is what you want http://sparkydirect.s3.amazonaws.com/1/1205P.jpg ?

Comment: With that solution you would drill a hole through the metal and grommet the hole. Without a drawing or more explanation we're kind of in the dark.

Comment: Does the connection need to be waterproof, resistant to temperature or pressure variations over the barrier? Do you need mechanical strain relief on the cables etc. Do you need to unplug one or both sides often, or is it permanent? 
The answer is very different if this is a pressure vessel or a toaster oven monitor

Comment: @shuckc, no, nothing needs to be pressure or watertight, nor is temperature a concern. I simply need to pass signals from a device on one side of the sheet to a device on the other. Yes, I will routinely need to adjust the wiring as the particular sensors need regular maintenance.

Comment: How many individual signal wires, and power lines do you need to couple. What are the voltages and signal frequencies?

Comment: @shuckc, I have 9 analog, 19 digital, and their respective grounds. Voltages are 0-10V, and most signals are on the order of a few Hertz, though I am also controlling a stepper motor via PWM: http://www.automationdirect.com/adc/Shopping/Catalog/Motion_Control/Stepper_Systems/Stepper_Drives_-z-_Power/STP-DRV-4035

Answer (score 1):

In general, electrical connectors that penetrate bulkheads, while maintaining vacuum, pressure, etc. and preventing shorting of the signal are called "feed throughs" and there are many types.  Here a particularly fancy and probably very expensive version.  They need not be fancy or expensive though.

[image]